# .net mvc @foreach id for table/cell

Tags: javascript, .net, json, model-view-controller

when loading the table, I want to execute a javascript on each row for cell 4.  This will format the json string that is being placed in it.

The way I have it coded is only updating the very first row/cell...

I'm thinking this will come down to correctly utilizing id and getElementById.

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.list)

        {
            <tr class="table-info">
                <td>@item.library</td>
                <td>@item.api</td>
                <td>@item.ibmiPgm</td>
                <td> <pre id="uglyPretty"></pre> </td>

                <script>

                    var obj = { "success": 1, "resultMessage": "Success", "list": [{ "custNo": "101", "firstName": "First Name: 101", "lastName": "Last Name: 101", "address1": "Address1: 101", "address2": "Address2: 101", "city": "City: 101", "state": "10", "zip": "101", "routing": "101", "accountNo": "101" }, { "custNo": "102", "firstName": "First Name: 102", "lastName": "Last Name: 102", "address1": "Address1: 102", "address2": "Address2: 102", "city": "City: 102", "state": "10", "zip": "102", "routing": "102", "accountNo": "102" }] };
                    document.getElementById("uglyPretty").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2);

                </script>

                <td>
                    <button typeof="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(item.api, "", new { api = item.api, jsonRequest = item.requestExample })'">Consume IBMi Core-iRST API</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

script section inside every table row.. amazing.. anyway - it works for first one because javascript is looking for element by Id. You have the same Id for each row but script will update first one found. If you have unique Id of each element you can:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.list)
    {
        <tr class="table-info">
            <td>@item.library</td>
            <td>@item.api</td>
            <td>@item.ibmiPgm</td>
            <td> <pre id="uglyPretty_@item.Id"></pre> </td>

            <script>

                var obj = { "success": 1, "resultMessage": "Success", "list": [{ "custNo": "101", "firstName": "First Name: 101", "lastName": "Last Name: 101", "address1": "Address1: 101", "address2": "Address2: 101", "city": "City: 101", "state": "10", "zip": "101", "routing": "101", "accountNo": "101" }, { "custNo": "102", "firstName": "First Name: 102", "lastName": "Last Name: 102", "address1": "Address1: 102", "address2": "Address2: 102", "city": "City: 102", "state": "10", "zip": "102", "routing": "102", "accountNo": "102" }] };
                document.getElementById("uglyPretty_@item.Id").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2);

            </script>

            <td>
                <button typeof="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(item.api, "", new { api = item.api, jsonRequest = item.requestExample })'">Consume IBMi Core-iRST API</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: thanks but see my answer for this!